# Beaglebone Debian ssh connection error

Tags: ssh, debian, putty, beagleboneblack, dropbear

I can't connect Putty or 192.168.7.2 from browser with Beaglebone. 
I overcome this situation at Angstrom with below codes .

```
rm dropbear_rsa_host_key
/etc/init.d/dropbear start
```

However, I can't handle it on Debian. There is no dropbear in /etc. **ssh_host_rsa_key** exist in debian.

I searched all internet but I couldnt find any solution. Please share your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried connecting over ssh like

```
ssh 192.168.7.2 -l root
```